# $[id*= ] with multiple elements

Tags: jquery

The following works in jQuery as I like to select all elements that contain CompanyID and triggers on change.

```
   $[id*=CompanyID].change(function () {
```

}

I also like to add if Id = 'OrganizationID' as well.

I tried the following but not working as it does not trigger:

```
     $('[id*=CompanyID]','[id=OrganizationID]').change(function () {
```

I tried the following but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put them in separate strings, the `,` should be part of the selector string:

```
$('[id*=CompanyID],[id=OrganizationID]').change(function () {
// No ' here ----^^^
```

That's a single string containing a [selector group](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#grouping).